# How can I include a Javascript style attribute into a variable without redefining the variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my very own package and I am trying to reduce the lines of code that I have, the example below is a close reflection of what I am doing but I have 25 more switch statements and I am tried that I have to re-type something like `break`(nothing I can do about it) but surely there is a way I can place `btn.style.backgroundColor`  inside a variable without redefining the variable? cause this will really help me alot.

```js
var i = 0; 
arr = ['black','red','yellow', 'green'];  
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(btn) {
 arr.forEach(function(){                
           switch(arr[i]) {
           case "black":
           btn.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
           break;
           case "yellow":
            btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
           break; 
           case "red": 
           btn.style.backgroundColor ='yellow'; 
           break;
           case "green": 
           btn.style.backgroundColor ='lime'; 
           break; 
           default: 
           btn.style.backgroundColor ='aqua'   
       }}) 
  i++
})
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: Since you are using `forEach()` you can access the array element directly in the callback instead of manually iterating `i`.  `forEach(function(color) {...});`

Comment: I've just deleted my answer because I'm not sure if I know what you want to achieve here. Could you describe it?

Comment: well, I would like it to be flexible for example, it checks for a class in the array and checks if the current element does contain the class, then perform the specified action. do you know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you can achieve what you want much easier:

```js
const arr = ['grey','yellow','red','lime'];  
[...document.querySelectorAll('button')]
  .forEach((btn,i)=>btn.style.backgroundColor = arr[i] || 'aqua')
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
```

As the original colours in your "key"-array were never used I simply left them out and used the array `arr` instead to hold the background colours.

Answer (score 1):

You use the outer `forEach` correctly, but the inner wrongly. Check the inner function argument: that's the element of the `arr` array:

```
arr = ['black','red','yellow', 'green'];  
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(btn) {
arr.forEach(function(a){                
           switch(a) {
           case "black":
           btn.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
           break;
           case "yellow":
            btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
           break; 
           case "red": 
           btn.style.backgroundColor ='yellow'; 
           break;
           case "green": 
           btn.style.backgroundColor ='lime'; 
           break; 
           default: 
           btn.style.backgroundColor ='aqua'   
       }}) 
})
```